# Language to Generate Powers of 2 Using a Language Containing Decimal Numbers

Tags: formal-languages

For this question, I have the alphabet $\Sigma=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. I also have the language $L$ over $\Sigma$ described as the language such that the strings $w$ contained in $L$ are powers of 2 and $w$ is treated as a decimal number. I then need to:

1. Design a grammar to generate $L$
2. Classify the grammar (Regular, Context-free, etc.)
3. Show that $L$ is not regular
4. Determine if $L$ is a context-free language (answering only yes or no)

The original question is in the image below, for reference.
[image: original problem]
I'm not entirely sure how to start on this question in particular. Most of the examples I had in my automata class consisted of much smaller alphabets and more precise languages. Any help with an explanation would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a reference to where you have this question from?

Comment: Probably context sensitive grammar (which lets you do about anything).

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is from anywhere in particular, or if the professor wrote it himself. It's from an optional assignment, but I'd like to figure it out.

Comment: In decimal form it is easy to see if a number is a power of 10. I doubt it helps.

Comment: Here's a clue: write a (context-sensitive) grammar which multiplies a decimal number by two. Use marker tokens which move right to left over the number; you'll need two of them because of the possibility of carry. The last question should be pretty easy to prove using by pumping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### L is not context-free

**Periodicity for context-free languages of bounded growth**: Let $w_n$ be the number of words of length $n$ in a given regular language. If the sequence $w_1, w_2, \cdots$ is bounded (bounded growth), then it is eventually periodic.

Proof: This follows from the fact that every context-free language of bounded growth is a union of paired loops, which is the theorem 2.1 in the paper [On a conjecture about slender
context-free languages](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82387063.pdf) by Lucian Ilie, 1994.

---

Let $w_n$ be the number of words of length $n$ in $L$. $w_n=\#\{k\in\Bbb N\mid n-1\le k\log_{10}2 \lt n\}$. Since $\log_{10}2$ is irrational, the sequence $w_1, w_2, \cdots$ cannot be eventually periodic. So $L$ is not context-free. Hence, it is not regular, either.

As rici pointed out, it is not difficult to prove that $L$ is not context free by applying the pumping lemma to any word in $L$ that is long enough. The above more conceptual proof is presented in the hope that it might raise more interest and more questions.

### $L$ is context-sensitive

According to [rici's comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/language-to-generate-powers-of-2-using-a-language-containing-decimal-numbers#comment232126_108662), we can write a context-sensitive grammar which multiplies a decimal number by two. Use marker tokens which move right to left over the number; you'll need two of them because of the possibility of carry. As with many other cases of context-sensitive grammars, the actual construction might be apt to get lengthy and tricky, sometimes even debatable.

Another conceptual way to see $L$ is context-sensitive is using [linear bounded automaton (LBA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton#LBA_and_context-sensitive_languages) that accepts a context-sensitive language. It is easy to see that we can divide by 2 repeatedly using a linear bounded automaton. More specifically, we can design a LBA such that given an input of $S m E$, where $m$ is a sequence of decimal digits and where $S$ and $E$ are start marker and end marker respectively, it will output $S1\square\square\cdots\square E$, where $\square$ stands for the special blank symbol if and only if $m$ is the decimal representation of some power of 2.

#### An exercise

Let language $L_U$ over $\Sigma=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ be the language of words which are positive integers whose prime factors belong to a finite set $U$ of prime numbers when they are treated as decimal numbers. Show that $L_U$ is context-sensitive but not context-free.